# Retrieve All Scrollable Elements from DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm new to javascript and as part of an chrome extension content script, I am trying to call a content script function whenever a DOM element scrolls.  I'm having difficulty with the step of selecting DOM elements with specific conditions:

Building on [Mike's solution][1]:

var condition1 = "[overflow = 'auto']";
    var condition2 = "[overflow = 'scroll']";
    var condition3 = clientHeight + border less than offsetHeight (unsure of syntax) 
    var condition 4 = clientWidth + border less than offsetWidth

```
//store elements matching conditions in arrays
var scrollable = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(condition1)); //convert nodelist into array
var scrollable2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(condition2));
var scrollable3 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(condition3));
var scrollable4 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(condition4));

    //concatenate arrays for a collection of desired elements
    var scrollable = scrollable.concat(scrollable2).concat(scrollable3).concat(scrollable4);
```

How should I structure the statements for conditions 3 and 4?

Is it possible to combine these conditions using the || operator?

Is the querySelectorAll() method the best method to use here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: How should I structure the statements for conditions 3 and 4?

Uh... I don't think there will be css selectors which could do calculate like that... Let me do some search and try to find out some solutions... Go down first...

> Q: Is it possible to combine these conditions using the || operator?

Yes. The param of the function *selectors* is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas. See [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for more details.

So you can use:

```
var condition = [condition1, condition2, condition3, condition4].join(', ');
var scrollable = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(condition));
```

> Q: Is the querySelectorAll() method the best method to use here?

Yes, I think it's a good way.

NOTE: Check out [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). You don't need to do

```
var scrollable = scrollable.concat(scrollable2).concat(scrollable3).concat(scrollable4);
```

Instead, you can do

```
var scrollable = scrollable.concat(scrollable2, scrollable3, scrollable4);
```

Comment: Thanks @iplus26, the operation to combine the variables (condition1, condition2...) is helpful.  It removes the need to concatenate at the end.  Thanks

Comment: @xyz You're welcome :) I'll be appreciate if you vote up my answer.

Comment: I have.  As I'm new to the forum, I need to get reputation pts before it is visible publicly.  Sorry

Comment: @xyz Yea.. Work harder and you'll get more reputation.